# PDF file getting corrupted and size increases when uploading it to FTP server | Android Studio | java

Tags: java, android, file, server, ftp-server

When I am uploading a pdf file to windows server it's getting corupted when downloading from FileZilla. The File size is also increasing in bytes.
Some files gets corrupted or some files only have half content.

Any help or code would be appreciated.
Thanks!

On Click to choose file from phone's directory:

```
   btnSelectFile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.setType("application/pdf");
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select PDF File"), 21);
        }
    });
```

On Activity Result:

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 21:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                // Get the Uri of the selected file
                uri = data.getData();
                uriString = uri.toString();
                myFile = new File(uriString);
                path = myFile.getAbsolutePath();
                displayName = null;
                file1 = Uri.fromFile(new File(path));

                if (uriString.startsWith("content://")) {
                    Cursor cursor = null;
                    try {
                        cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
                        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                            displayName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME));
                            textFileSelectedOrNot.setText(displayName);
                            fileName = textFileSelectedOrNot.getText().toString();
                        }
                    } finally {
                        cursor.close();
                    }
                } else if (uriString.startsWith("file://")) {
                    displayName = myFile.getName();
                    textFileSelectedOrNot.setText(displayName);
                    fileName = textFileSelectedOrNot.getText().toString();
                }
            }

            break;
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Creating directory on server and uploading file:

```
  class CreateDir extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

        String server = "XX.XXX.X.XX";
        String username = "XXXXXXX";
        String password = "XXXXX";

        FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
        try {

            ftpClient.connect(server, 2102);
            ftpClient.login(username, password);
            ftpClient.setFileTransferMode(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
            ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();

            Log.d(TAG, "CONNECTED");

            String dirPath = "/ws.gajeratrust.org/TestingApp/" + fileId + "/";
            boolean created = ftpClient.makeDirectory(dirPath);

            FTPUtils.mkdir(ftpClient, dirPath);


       InputStream inputStream =getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
       ftpClient.storeFile(dirPath+"/"+fileName,inputStream);
       
       inputStream.close();



            ftpClient.logout();
            ftpClient.disconnect();
            Log.d(TAG, "DISCONNECTED");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Please check the code any alterations or something I have coded wrong, please comment it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);

Replace that by

```
InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData());
```

You can throw away all code messing around with File and Cursor instances.

Also i wonder what those four lines before the line i quoted should do.

Comment: Sir, there is also one question, the file is getting corrupted. Any thoughts on that.

Comment: Please show new code first. You could need a cursor to obtain the file name indeed. And set the transfer mode to binary.

Comment: Sir I have changed the code that you  quoted in the question. I have not set any transfer mode. All the code related to uploading file is here only.

Comment: Then if for the rest it works you should set transfermode to binary.

Comment: The transfer mode will be text by default. In this mode every \n will be send/received as \r\n. So the received file has more bytes. You did not mention that.

Comment: i have set  ftpClient.setFileTransferMode(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE); then also mostly file getting corrupted or half content only shows.

Comment: Please mention file size of original and copy in bytes.

Comment: My god... You set the transfer mode after storing the file.... Should i say more???

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I was setting the transfer mode incorrect way.
Right way is :

```
      ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
      ftpClient.setFileTransferMode(FTP.STREAM_TRANSFER_MODE);
```

Comment: in my case: ftpClient.setType(FtpClient.TransferType.BINARY); Thanks all!!!!!!